# El registro no se Borra, SQL Server AdventuresWork

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Buenas estoy en un problema con esta consulta que me pide:

**Eliminar todos los productos (Production.Product) cuyo ProductNumber empiece por BA**

las lineas que de comando que estoy utilizando son:

`delete from Production.Product where ProductNumber like 'BA%'`

el error que me arroja es este:

**Instrucción DELETE en conflicto con la restricción REFERENCE 'FK_BillOfMaterials_Product_ComponentID'. El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos 'AdventureWorks2008R2', tabla 'Production.BillOfMaterials', column 'ComponentID'.**

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No hay ningun error. Estas tratando de borrar productos que por integridad referencial no pueden ser borrados porque existen donde te dice el mensaje... deberias borrarlo primero de ahi...

Comment: ... no entiendo, no hay formar de eliminar el registro?... gracias por la recomendacion de como preguntar

Comment: No si tiene datos referenciados en otras tablas... lee sobre integridad referencial....

Answer (score 0):

No puedes eliminar registros que son referentes de columnas de otras tablas, en pocas palabras, no puedes eliminar datos que son foreigns keys en otras tablas.

Te pongo un ejemplo (y lo haré con sintaxis de MSSQL Server porque no sé si lo que tienes es MySQL o SQL Server); tengo la tabla `MM_CONDUCTOR` y deseo ver las referencias que tiene, para ello puedo hacer uso de `ALT+F1` si estoy en SSMS o usar este script:

```sql
exec sp_help 'MM_CONDUCTOR'
```

Acá por ejemplo me sale lo siguiente:

```sql
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|constraint_type        |constraint_name        |constraint_keys                          |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+
|FOREIGN KEY            |MM_CONDUCTOR_IT_EMPRESA|Empresa                                  |
|                       |                       |REFERENCES BDTRC.dbo.IT_EMPRESA (Empresa)|
|PRIMARY KEY (clustered)|MM_CONDUCTOR_pk        |Conductor                                |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

Ves que ahí me resalta claramente `REFERENCES BDTRC.dbo.IT_EMPRESA (Empresa)`, por tanto en esta tabla tengo una columna que hace referencia a la columna `Empresa` de mi tabla `IT_EMPRESA`, es decir, que si quisiera eliminar un registro de esa columna me lanzaría el error que tú tienes, observa:

```sql
delete from IT_EMPRESA where Empresa = 1
```

```sql
[23000][547] Line 1: The DELETE statement conflicted 
with the REFERENCE constraint "MM_CONDUCTOR_IT_EMPRESA". 
The conflict occurred in database "BDTRC", table "dbo.MM_CONDUCTOR", 
column 'Empresa'.
```

Esto no es como tal considerado error, más que todo advertencia, porque así fueron establecidas tus tablas y restricciones, para alterar esto hay opciones como `on delete cascade`.

Saludos.